# Multiple image show from server in a sliding form

Tags: android, androidimageslider

I am new to android and i want to make a image slider as used in zomato and tinder app. I have n number of images coming from server and i want to show it in a slider form with dot indicators. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPager to swipe the activities or fragments that contain the images, then in every fragment or activity, do the content or make them load the content you want to be displayed